# can I insert a set into a map with set as the value in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, set

```
map<int, set<int>> m;
set<int> n;
m[1].insert(3);
n.insert(3);
n.insert(4);
m[1].insert(n);   //can I do this?
```

Is the last line correct? If not, any easy approach to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: You must think of it like this. Who's function is insert ? It is of a map or set ?. Set ofcourse; so you cannot insert a set to a set here. Hence a range is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the last line correct?

No. What you want should be [inserting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) elements from another `std::set`, you could

```
m[1].insert(n.begin(), n.end()); // insert all the elements of n into m[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this will be like this:

```
m[1] = n;
```

But this will overwrite whatever was previously inserted into `m[1]`.

To add to the previously inserted elements, you can use range overload of `insert`

```
m[1].insert(n.begin(), n.end());
```